# How to count particular value in a field of a table in codeigniter query command

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to do a report and for this I need to fetch and count the number of child's of each employee if married. I tried a way but its only getting one employee information when add the asterik line in query else its fetch all employee's information as a beginner I don't know why . relation are coming from a array . I am giving the array here with table and my code to understand ! let me remind you I want child's total thats mean total of son and daughter not only son or daughter total .

this is the relation array ;

```
        $config['relation'] = array(                    
                '1' => 'father',
                '2' => 'mother',
                '3' => 'brother',
                '4' => 'sister',
                '5' => 'husband',
                '6' => 'wife',
                '7' => 'son',
                '8' => 'daughter',
                '9' => 'uncle',
                '10' => 'unty',
                '11' => 'cousin',
                '13' => 'grand father',
                '14' => 'grand mother', 

                );
```

this is the database table to fetch

```
 EMP_FAMILY_ID  EMP_ID  NAME    NAME_BENGALI    RELATION BIRTH_DATE     AGE OCCPATION   CONTACT_NO          
    1           1       fghn    vbn             7        2000-09-02     15      4       23546585        
    2           1       dgh     dfgh            7        2003-10-02     12      4       453273      
    3           1       fghjm   fgn             8        1970-01-01     14      4       4520752         
    4           1       fgbbn   bmnbnm          8        1970-01-01     14      4       4532        
    5           2       bfhb    fghfg           5        1970-01-01     20      8       634565
    6           3       bfhb    fghfg           6        1970-01-01     20      9       634565




     $query = $this->db->select('

                                emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME_BENGALI,
                                emp.EMPLOYEE_FATHER_BENGALI,
                                emp.EMPLOYEE_MOTHER_BENGALI,
                                emp.BIRTH_DATE,
                                emp.EMP_BLOOD_GROUP,
                                emp.MARITAL_STATUS,
                                emp.EMP_JOB_NATURE,
                                emp.QUOTA_ID,
                                **sum(case when emf.RELATION="7" || emf.RELATION="8" then 1 else 0 end) as son,**
                                ')

                                ->from('hrm_ls_employee as emp')
                                ->join('hrm_ls_emp_family as emf','emp.EMP_ID = emf.EMP_ID','left')

                                ->where('emp.IS_DELETED',0) 
                                ->order_by('emp.EMP_ID')
                                ->get();




           $emp_details_report = $query->result();
```

Comment: and if anyone have any suggestion about how can i learn this type of query where anything to do with targeted fields  pls mention it !

Comment: You can use num_rows() function to get count

Comment: thank's for your comment ! but i think u did not get the point ! i want to retrive for each employee's  how many 7 and 8 value is there in the table field called " RELATION " so that i can show child number .

Comment: i think i am unlucky today  that  no one  to help me !